Problem in python with pynput.keyboard module
I work with Anaconda and Spyder.
I have a Python code that does some web scraping, and it worked fine until I updated Anaconda and Spyder a few days ago.
I'm having trouble with simulating writing or pressing keys when the webpage opens. The code thinks it actually goes through those steps and then continues with the next part of the code, but in reality, writing or pressing keys never happens.
This is some part of the code I have trouble with:
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

# Permite escribir en automatico "keyboard.type"
keyboard = Controller()

# Definir nombre de usuario
user_name = 'user_name'

# Escribir nombre de usuario en la ventana emergente
keyboard.type(user_name)

# Pasar a escribir en el campo de contraseña
keyboard.press(Key.tab)

# Definir contraseña
password = 'Password'

# Escribir contraseña en la ventana emergente
keyboard.type(password)

# Entrar al portal
keyboard.press(Key.enter)

It worked fine before I updated Anaconda and Spyder, but now it doesn't simulate writing the username or password and doesn't press any key, either.
I have tried uninstalling and installing again the pynput module. Any idea how to fix it? Or a workaround using another module?

There are a lot of keyboard modules out there to choose from, so if pynput doesn't work, then you can always use keyboard, which is one of the popular choices. However, using other modules to scrape a webpage is horribly messy, I'm pretty sure the web scraping platform you are using can simulate key presses as well as pynput.

I ran the exact same code in a Jupyter Notebook, and it ran as it was supposed to; the writing and pressing of keys did happen. Any idea on how to fix it in Spyder?
